# ¿ Ir a un sitio por su IP alojado en servidor IIS que comparte la misma IP para varios sitios?

Tags: web, iis, dns

Como puedo acceder a un sitio web alojado en un servidor IIS mediante su IP teniendo en cuenta que varios sitios comparten la misma IP del servidor. Además también debo de acceder por su nombre de dominio.

He probado como:

Donde vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz = IP

```
vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz/~mihost
vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz:mihost
vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz:puerto:mihost
```

pero no funciona

Comment: pues debes saber si tu equipo puede resolver esa dirección IP, en consola de comandos haces "ping ip", si equipo no puede resolver la IP es porque tu equipo no puede ver el servidor y eso es lo que debes resolver primero

Comment: Puedo ver la IP del equipo. Pero esa IP es compartida por varios sitios alojados en el servidor mediante IIS

Comment: iis solo puede mostrar un sitio por puerto y esto no se puede cambiar, si quieres ver mas sitios tienes que usar las opciones que te explicaron en las respuestas, al crear varios sitios los verás así http://vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz:puerto/index.html (Ej: http://1.1.1.1:80/index.html)

ojo que como estás usando una IP, es importante agregar el 'http://', segunda cosa importante es agregar el index.html (o el archivo de página inicial) ya que puede que no este configurado (esto se puede configurar en la seccion 'Default Document' del sitio web en el IIS o en el web config)

Comment: con respecto a lo de "virtual directory", pues aquí tienes otra opción aparte de virtual directory la cual es Application. Virtual Directory te crea un puntero a otra carpeta haciendo que esa aplicación viva dentro de la misma aplicación raíz, esto significa que comparten variables globales como Application, Session, etc. Mientras que Application te crea otra aplicación y lo único que comparte de la raíz es el nombre. En ambos casos te crea rutas como las siguientes: http://vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz:puerto/virtualdirectory/index.html o http://vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz:puerto/application/index.html

Comment: se me olvido comentar que las aplicaciones y directorios virtuales comparten el nombre y puerto por lo que puedes habilitar el sitio web por defecto en el puerto 80 y luego los "sub-sitios web" que desees

Comment: @LPZadkiel como comento mas abajo me funciona a medias. En el entorno de pruebas en localhost, solo me va la opción si lo hago como "Crear aplicación" y no como "Directorio Virtual" además le tengo puesto un puerto por defecto a ese sitio.

Comment: En cambio en el entorno real intento hacer lo mismo como "Crear aplicación" pero en este caso no le pongo un puerto por defecto sino solo el alias. Al entrar con el explorador como vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz/alias me responde con un HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Comment: puedes entrar a http://vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz/ (mostrandote la página por defecto del iis) pero no puedes entrar a http://vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz/alias? es ese el problema actual que tienes?

Comment: Si pongo solo vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz en el  servidor de producción me responde con un HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found. Si pongo el nombre del dominio si que me muestra el sitio. Si pongo el alias vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz/alias tampoco me muestra el sitio. Supongo que tendre que poner también un puerto y ponerlo como vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz:puerto/alias o vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz:puerto. Si abro ese puerto diferente al 80 ¿ Puede comprometer la seguridad del servidor ?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos opciones. La primera sería crear un sitio web predeterminado, en el puerto por defecto (80) y crear un directorio virtual para cada sitio web que desees (en el administrador de IIS, menú contextual sobre el sitio web, Añadir directorio virtual).

Se accedería con
    `vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz/mihost1`
    `vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz/mihost2`
    `...`
    `vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz/mihostn`

La segunda opción es asignar un puerto distinto para cada sitio web, y accederías con una url del tipo `vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz` en el sitio web por defecto (puerto 80) o `vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz:81` (en caso de asignarle el puerto 81).

Comment: Se me olvido comentar que también quiero acceder a la vez por el nombre del dominio sin tener que poner puerto o directorio virtual. Es decir podría entrar al sitio como nombremisitio.com o vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz/mihost1 o vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz:81 Es posible?

Comment: @Popularfan Por supuesto, da igual la IP que el nombre del dominio. Si utilidas un número de puerto distinto de 80 deberás tener en cuenta que tu Firewall tenga ese puerto abierto.

Comment: No me funciona bien. Tengo un entorno de pruebas en localhost con una IP del tipo 192.168.0.10 agrego el sitio en el puerto 7070 y luego dentro de este sitio creo un directorio virtual con alias 'imagen'. Si intento acceder como 192.168.0.10:7070/imagen no funciona ya que me sale un error de web.config. En cambio si hago esto como "Crear Aplicación" en vez de Directorio Virtual me funciona correctamente con la IP 192.168.10:7070/imagen

Comment: Por otro lado a la hora de hacer esto en el servidor con la IP Publica intento hacer lo mismo creando un directorio virtual o creando aplicación pero no me funciona de ninguna de las dos maneras. No se si tendría que asignar además un puerto especifico como lo he hecho en el entorno de pruebas en localhost para que me funcione almenos con el modo de "Crear Aplicación". Asi tener vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz/imagen en vez de vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz:puerto/imagen

Comment: Si te funciona con localhost y creando una aplicación, y con la IP pública no funciona, el problema es de routing o bien de firewall. Desde el exterior, tienes una IP pública, que es la de tu router, este debe saber redireccionar las peticiones a un puerto determinado (o un nombre de dominio) a la IP interna y la máquina donde tienes las webs deben permitir el acceso (en su firewall) por el puerto indicado.

Comment: No creo que sea problema de firewall ya que a la pagina puedo acceder mediante el nombre de dominio y además puedo entrar en remoto mediante esa IP. Yo creo que alomejor es que debo además asignar un puerto. ¿ Sino como va a diferenciar diferentes sitios desde una misma IP ?

Comment: Primero haz una prueba. Pon la web en el puerto 80 y mira si funciona.

Comment: Puedo entrar a la web perfectamente con nombrededominio:80 pero en el IIS tengo varios sitios con el mismo puerto 80. Por eso creo que alomejor debería poner un puerto diferente si quiero usar además un alias como vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz:puerto/alias en vez de solo vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz/alias